# c# adjacency matrix scorpion

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a problem starting this task: 
An n-vertex graph is a scorpion if it has a vertex of degree 1(the sting) connected to a vertex of degree two (the tail) connected a vertex of degree n-2 (the body) connected to the other n-3 (the feet). Some of the feet may be connected to other feet. Design an algorithm that decides whether a given drawing represents a scorpion.
.
I should make adjacency matrix and then try to search basically for sting which has only one connection with tail and do the same thing with tail and body...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Vertex Edges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561896/c-sharp-vertex-edges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by determining the degree of each vertex (from adjacency matrix or adjacency lists or any other way this is possible), then choose the one vertex of degree `n-2` as body center (there is just one such vertex if `n > 4` and your graph is a spider, also there should be no vertex of degree `n-1`). The sting head is the one vertex that the body center is not adjacent to if the graph is a spider. Check the sting head has degree 1. And then you check that the sting head is connected to a vertex of degree 2 (i.e. the sting-tail articulation). If `n <= 4`, you only get degenerated spiders (for `n=4`, the spider has one leg, for `n=3` the spider has no legs, for `n=2`, `n=1` or `n=0` you can't have a spider).